# Disable macro effect with beamerarticle

Tags: beamerarticle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\textcolor<3->{red}{Some text}
\end{document}
```

The previous code compiles fine thanks to the `beamerarticle` package. However, I do not only want it to compile but also to completely disable the overlay effect: in this case I want the text to stay black (as it is in the first two frames) when printed into an article.

Is this possible?

**Edit.** My use-case is the following: I have a collection of problems typeset in LaTeX that I use both as content for beamer slides and as source for printed material.
Each problem is in his custom file, so I have something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mybeamertheme}
\begin{document}
\mycustomimportcommand{problem1}
\mycustomimportcommand{problem4}
...
\end{document}
```

And then on another file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycustomarticleformatting}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\mycustomimportcommand{problem1}
\mycustomimportcommand{problem4}
...
\end{document}
```

Since the problems are typeset for a presentation, the code is filled with overlay specs: `\pause`, `\only`, etc. that I want to be ignored when I'm importing the code into articles.

This works fine except when there are overlay aware macros as shown in the MWE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you want to use `beamerarticle` at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer because I'm importing code from a beamer presentation, full of overlay specs that of course I do not want when printing an article.

Comment: You should add that information to your post

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought it was obvious, will do it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is not with the `overlay` specification but with `\textcolor` command. When used inside a `beamerarcicle`, command `\textcolor<1->{red}{Some text}` is converted to `\textcolor{red}{Some text}` and `Some text` is written in red color.

I can think in two solutions, the first one would be to use

```
\mode<article>{Some text}\mode<beamer>{\textcolor<1->{red}{Some text}}
```

but I imagin this is too much work.

A second workarround could be to redefine all your colors to black when `beamerarticle` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\mode<article>
{
    \colorlet{red}{black}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textcolor<2->{red}{Some text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\renewcommand<>{\textcolor}[2]{\iffalse#1\fi#2}
\begin{document}
\textcolor<3->{red}{Some text}
\end{document}
```

However this is a sub-optimal solution since I still have to redefine each overlay aware macro, would still be nice to have a more general/simple solution